# How to handle GDAL dataset error when accessing Arcgis Online world imagery data?

Tags: qgis, gdal

I would like to use the world imagery data set for loading base maps to my QGIS projects. Up until now, I have had no problem by typing the following command in the Python console:

```
qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")
```

Yet, now I am getting the following error message:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

- I am using QGIS version 2.8.2 and GDAL version 1.11.2

Comment: version of QGIS? version of GDAL?

Comment: My version of QGIS is 2.8.2 and GDAL is 1.11.2.